# Fastest way to empty a lot of divs, by class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment I'm using `$('.class:not(:empty)').html('');` and it still takes too long for me.

For example, takes ~2 seconds with ~1200 non-empty divs and ~2000 divs in total.

Also, would it be faster to simply remove the divs entirely?

Comment: Why don't you just try to `.remove` them?

Comment: Fastest way  is : JS. not jQ.

Comment: Why have you got all those empty divs in the first place?

Comment: @jeff for the sake of clarity: I'm working on changing a Gantt chart that can span up to 5 years and have up to 10 000 lines which at certain sizes becomes too much memory for the client's browser to maintain so I'm implementing a way to generate it only for the vicinity of the viewport. Those empty divs are the skelleton of the graph, mainly the individual months for every line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try with:

```
$('.class').empty();
```

You will not filter all `.class`es for non-empty ones which takes time - just clear all of them.

Performance test:

```
$('.class').empty();               // 23.810ms, 31.646ms, 24.003ms ~ 26,486ms
$('.class:not(:empty)').empty();   // 25.469ms, 27.323ms, 24.964ms ~ 25,919ms

$('.class').html('');              // 34.353ms, 48.778ms, 44.487ms ~ 42,539ms
$('.class:not(:empty)').html('');  // 34.751ms, 27.494ms, 35.428ms ~ 32,558ms
```

And simple removing of all items:

```
$('.class').remove;                // 77.650ms, 68.968ms, 69.281ms ~ 71,966ms
```

This test was made with:

```
$('body').empty()
for (var i = 0; i < 1200; i++) $('<div class="class">not-empty</div>').appendTo($('body'));
for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) $('<div class="class"></div>').appendTo($('body'));

console.time('timer');
  // proper method
console.timeEnd('timer')
```

Comment: Doesn't it take more time to run .empty() on the non-empty ones than to filter them out?

Comment: @Bogdan I did some tests. As you can see, there is no difference betwen `.class` and `.class:not(:empty)` in the first pair of test. However the key of the performance in your problem is to use `.empty()` instead of `.html('')`.

Comment: @Bogdan Removing this bunch of divs takes much more time than clearing.

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive answer. I just made the change and the run time of the functions using it halved for most of the tests and did 30% better for worst case scenario.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$("div.ClassName").html('');
```

**or**

```
$("div.ClassName").empty();
```